# Java Reactor inapporiate blocking method inside Mono flatMap method

Tags: project-reactor

This part of code inside mono.flatMap(() -> ()) is giving me an error(or warning?) `verifyClient.sms(request.phoneNumber()`. Error is "Inappropriate blocking method call".  I guess SMS call is a blocking call from a third party(TeleSign) sdk.

Error is shown in the picture.

```
    @Override
public Mono<ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse>> postSms(
        Mono<SendSmsDetail> sendSmsDetail, ServerWebExchange exchange) {

    return sendSmsDetail.doOnNext(this::validate)
            .flatMap(request -> {
                try {
                    return Mono.just(verifyClient.sms(request.phoneNumber(),
                                                      buildSmsParam(request)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Fail to verify", e));
                }
            })
            .onErrorResume(this::defaultOrderErrorHandler);
}
```

Screenshot of the error:
[image]

Can someone please tell me how to resolve it?  Just started using Reactor. By the way, if you notice the screenshot and the actual pasted code has differences on `.flatMap(tlr -> tlr.)` part.  Code currently won't compile due to **different return type.**  I am also trying to make it compile by returning `Mono<ResponseEntity<SuccessResponse>>`.  That's what I am trying to do with the second flatMap.  Change "tlr"(TeleSignResponse) to my own "SuccessResponse".

I may need a second post on how to make this compile.

Comment: Your SMS library is blocking - it cannot be used with Reactor. You can, as a workaround, wrap that `Mono` in another thread pool that executes the blocking tasks.

Comment: On the second part, you likely want `map` not `flatMap`.

Comment: Also, use Reactors exception propagation tools. Don’t wrap exceptions by hand - that’s going to cause you all sorts of problems in the long term...  https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/core/Exceptions.html

Comment: SMS library being blocking, does that mean it is better off for me to call Mono.defer( () -> { } ) and use CompleteableFuture with this library? Thanks for the info on the exception propagation tool.

Comment: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1756. Found a way to handle blocking in Reactor.

Comment: Yes, what you found is how you place execution on another thread pool ;). It’s a workaround and will obviously be a bottleneck to the scalability of your reactive pipeline. If it’s not a problem then you might want to ask yourself why you’re using Reactor - as you obviously don’t need the scale it can supply. There are legitimate reasons to use Reactor in an environment where blocking is necessary, but you really need to think deeply about whether adding the complexity of Reactor is going to give you any benefit at all.